# Given a hash with an array of values, how to extract numbers of unique values of each key?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a hash that has an array of values for each key:

```
h = {
  'a' => ['c', 'b', 'd'],
  'b' => ['c', 'b', 'f', 'g']
}
```

I need to return a hash `g` that gives the number of "unique" values of each key in `h`. For example, `h['a']` has 2 values (`'c'` and `b'`) that are not unique in the sense that they are present in `h['b']`. In that case the value of `'a'` in `g` should equal `1` since `'d'` is the only unique element of `h['a']`. The same goes for the key `'b'`. It has 2 common values with `'a'` in `h`, but 2 unique ones as well (`'f'` and `g'`). So in my case the `g` should equal `{'a' => 1,`b`=> 2}`.

I have tried `h.select { |_,a| a.size == 1 }`, but it returns an empty hash.

Also, I have a way of returning the unique values but when I'm trying to write the Rspec test it fails, the solution I have is the following:

```
@split_log_file.each { |key, array|
  "#{key} has #{array.uniq.length} unique visitors" }
```

Comment: I don't understand your desired output `{ 'a' => 1, c => '2' }` from your input. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: Can you explain how `{'a' => 1, c => '2'}` is an extract of the "unique values" for the input?

Comment: @maxpleaner Sure, for example the key 'a' has 2 values(c, b) that are not unique, because they are present in 'b' also.  In that case it should return { 'a' => 1} since 'd' is the unique value. Same goes for 'b' that has 2 common values with a, but 2 unique ones as well.

Comment: It appears you mean, "extract the *number* of unique values for each key", not the unique values themselves. If so, please edit. You also need to explain what you mean by "unique".

Comment: Whenever you give an example it's helpful to assign a variable to each input. (Here `h = {...}`, from my edit.) That way readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them, and all readers refer to the same variable names. You may also find it helpful to make the statement of the question precise and unambiguous (see my edit of your question). Lastly, it facilitates cut-and-paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code would work with more than two keys also

```
h = {
  'a' => ['c', 'b', 'd'],
  'b' => ['c', 'b', 'f', 'g']
}
g={}

all_values = h.values.flatten
uniq_elements = all_values.select{|element| all_values.count(element) == 1 }
h.each do |k,v|
  g[k] = (v & uniq_elements).count
end
g
```

If we don't want to check duplicates in self array of hash then we can collect uniq like below

```
h = { 'cat' => ['c', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'e', 'f'],
      'dog' => ['c', 'b', 'f', 'g'],
      'pig' => ['h', 'h', 'b', 'f'] }

g={}

all_values = h.values.collect{|val| val.uniq}.flatten
uniq_elements = all_values.select{|element| all_values.count(element) == 1 }
h.each do |k,v|
  g[k] = (v & uniq_elements).count
end
g
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland - Here in this example value itself has a duplicate. I have updated my answer to skip the duplicate in self array.

Answer (score 2):

This should meet your requirements.

```
def uniqify(h)
  keys = h.keys
  keys.each_with_object({}) { |k,g| g[k] =
    (keys-[k]).reduce(h[k]) { |a,kk| a-h[kk] }.uniq.size } }
end
```

```
h = { 'cat' => ['c', 'b', 'e', 'f', 'c'],
      'dog' => ['c', 'b', 'f', 'g', 'h'] }

uniqify h
  #=> {"cat"=>1, "dog"=>2}
```

```
h = { 'cat' => ['c', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'e', 'f'],
      'dog' => ['c', 'b', 'f', 'g'],
      'pig' => ['h', 'h', 'b', 'f'] }

uniqify h
  #=> {"cat"=>2, "dog"=>1, "pig"=>1}
```

See [Array#-](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-2D).

Comment: @Stefan, I was [asleep at the switch](https://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/asleep+at+the+switch.html). Fixed.